# jQuery: Reset classes once the field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

**NOTE:**
The following solution comes from [THIS TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024768/jquery-select-identical-numbers-from-a-table), please see that first.

I have 11 inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="[something]-input inputs">
```

(Where `[something]` is a name, different for every input)

```
$(document).on("change", ".inputs", function(){
    var thisclass = $(this).attr('class').split("-")[0];
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        //
    }
    highlightInputNumbers(thisclass, 0);

});
```

The `highlightInputNumbers` function goes this way:

```
function highlightInputNumbers(classe, stepcount, empty){

        var all= $("td[class*="+classe+"]");
        var index = all.length-1;
        var concat_steps = $(all[index]).html().split('.')

        //var due_serie = $(all[index]).html().split('.')

        var due_serie = $('.'+classe+'-input').val().split('.')

        for (var i = index; i >= (index-stepcount)+2; i--) {
            due_serie = due_serie.concat($(all[i-1]).html().split('.'));
        };

        //Rimuovo i doppioni
        var serieCompleta = [];
        $.each(due_serie, function(i, el){
            if($.inArray(el, serieCompleta) === -1) serieCompleta.push(el);
        });

        //Ottengo dati          

        for(var s = 0; s < index-(stepcount-1); s++){

            var bar = $(all[s]);
            var barnum = bar.html().split('.');
            bar.html('');

            var found = 0;

            for(i = 0; i<= barnum.length-1; i++){

               for(n = 0; n<= serieCompleta.length-1; n++){

                  if(i != 4){ var punto = '.' }else{ var punto = ''}

                      /* Problem here:*/
                      if(barnum[i] == serieCompleta[n]){
                        bar.append('<span class="highlight">'+barnum[i]+'</span><span class="fade">'+punto+'</span>');
                        found = barnum[i];
                      }
                 }

               if(barnum[i] != found){
                bar.append('<span class="fade">'+barnum[i]+punto+'</span>');
               }
             }

          }
      }
```

Where I commented `/*Problem here*/` is where I highlight the numbers in the column (that I have inserted), but if I remove the numbers in the input they stay highlighted... If I change them it keeps the old ones..

As you can see here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2276958/Cols_and_rows.mov

Comment: Have you tried to handle the `on input` event instead of `on change`?

Comment: Also, if what do you want is to highlight the input that has had its value edited, you could refer to it just by `$(this)`.

Comment: It's a bit hard to propose a solution without the relevant markup (table), but have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/6amtxkzt/1/

Comment: Tks @MelanciaUK. Please see the NOTE I placed at the beginning of the post.

Comment: @Mr.Web Can include `html` at Question ? Is requirement to highlight `tr` elements which contain same numbers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small addition in your code.
Let me try to explain what was happening in your code.

At first try:

1. your code gets the input values (eg. 89.30.20)
2. Loop through all available values in the table
3. Split each value by '.'
4. Then loop through these spitted values to check for match and highlight
5. **Replace** the **matched number** to **highlighted span** (i.e 20 to 20 and **unmatched number** to **faded span**.

   This all works for first time. But at the second try, your **code breaks** from **step 3**. As in step 3 code tries to split values by '.' but the values were replaced with Span values in your first try. So now to rectify this issue I added small check and 2-3 lines of extra code to extract actual values from Span values.

That extra code is:

```
    // Check if values bar already contains Span tags (means already processed in first try 
    var hasSpans = bar.find('span').length>0;
    if(hasSpans) 
    {
      //If yes then extract the actual values from these span tags without '.' (This will work for all tries after FIRST)
      barnum=bar.find('span').map(
      function() { 
      if($(this).html() != '.') 
        return $(this).html().replace('.','');
      }).get();
      }
   // else normal case, split the values by '.' (This will for very FIRST try)
   else barnum = bar.html().split('.');
```

```js
$(document).on("change", ".inputs", function(){
    var thisclass = $(this).attr('class').split("-")[0];
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        //
    }
    highlightInputNumbers(thisclass, 0);

});


function highlightInputNumbers(classe, stepcount, empty){

        var all= $("td[class*="+classe+"]");
        var index = all.length-1;
        var concat_steps = $(all[index]).html().split('.')

        //var due_serie = $(all[index]).html().split('.')

        var due_serie = $('.'+classe+'-input').val().split('.')

        for (var i = index; i >= (index-stepcount)+2; i--) {
            due_serie = due_serie.concat($(all[i-1]).html().split('.'));
        };

        //Rimuovo i doppioni
        var serieCompleta = [];
        $.each(due_serie, function(i, el){
            if($.inArray(el, serieCompleta) === -1) serieCompleta.push(el);
        });

        //Ottengo dati          
        for(var s = 0; s < index-(stepcount-1); s++){
            
            
            var bar = $(all[s]);
            var barnum;
            var hasSpans = bar.find('span').length>0;
            if(hasSpans) 
              {
                barnum=bar.find('span').map(
                  function() { 
                    if($(this).html() != '.') 
                      return $(this).html().replace('.','');
                     }).get();
              }
            else barnum = bar.html().split('.');
            bar.html('');

            var found = 0;

            for(i = 0; i<= barnum.length-1; i++){

               for(n = 0; n<= serieCompleta.length-1; n++){

                  if(i != 4){ var punto = '.' }else{ var punto = ''}

                      /* Problem here:*/
                      if(barnum[i] == serieCompleta[n]){
                        bar.append('<span class="highlight">'+barnum[i]+'</span><span class="fade">'+punto+'</span>');
                        found = barnum[i];
                      }
                 }

               if(barnum[i] != found){
                bar.append('<span class="fade">'+barnum[i]+punto+'</span>');
               }
             }

          }
      }
```

```css
span.highlight{
  color:green;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>02/05/2015</td><td class="bari1">89.10.86.30.65</td></tr>
<tr><td>30/04/2015</td><td class="bari2">96.11.73.36.13</td></tr>
<tr><td>02/05/2015</td><td class="bari3">78.34.50.72.11</td></tr>
<tr><td>30/04/2015</td><td class="bari4">34.78.69.60.22</td></tr>
<tr><td>02/05/2015</td><td class="bari5">12.29.30.69.33</td></tr>
<tr><td>30/04/2015</td><td class="bari6">59.10.20.96.44</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="text" class="bari-input inputs"></td></tr>
</table>


<table>
<tr><td>02/05/2015</td><td class="vari1">89.10.86.30.65</td></tr>
<tr><td>30/04/2015</td><td class="vari2">96.11.73.36.13</td></tr>
<tr><td>02/05/2015</td><td class="vari3">78.34.50.72.11</td></tr>
<tr><td>30/04/2015</td><td class="vari4">34.78.69.60.22</td></tr>
<tr><td>02/05/2015</td><td class="vari5">12.29.30.69.33</td></tr>
<tr><td>30/04/2015</td><td class="vari6">59.10.20.96.44</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="text" class="vari-input inputs"></td></tr>
</table>
```